# Are you charged for accessing the AWS Cost Explorer dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's an extract from the AWS documentation:

"*You can view your costs and usage using the Cost Explorer user interface free of charge. You can also access your data programmatically using the Cost Explorer API. Each paginated API request incurs a charge of $0.01. You can't disable Cost Explorer after you enable it.*"

Does that mean I'm not going to be charged for accessing the cost explorer dashboard? If that's the case, why is the cost explorer disabled by default?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Reference seems to be: [Analyzing Your Costs with Cost Explorer - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-what-is.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will be charged if you access the cost access programmatically using the cost explorer APIs, and the cost will depend on number of records in it.